# Continuous inculsion of the dual of continuous included Banach spaces

Tags: banach-spaces, duality-theorems

If $B$ and $C$ are Banach spaces and $B \subset C$ with the inclusion being continuous. If it true that the set of continuous linear functionals on $C$, $C'$, is continuous included in the set of continuous linear functionals on $B$, $B'$:
$$ C' \subset B'$$
If it is true how do I prove it?

Comment: have you tried to see if this is true when $B$ and $C$ are finite dimensional vector spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $\|x\|_C\le\alpha\|x\|_B$ for all $x\in B$ and some $\alpha > 0$. Define $\Phi : C'\to B'$ by $\Phi f := f|B$. Since for $x\in B$ we have
$$
|(f|B)x| = |fx|\le\|f\|_{C'}\|x\|_C\le\alpha\|f\|_{C'}\|x\|_B,
$$
$\Phi$ is well defined. Now, it remains for you to show that $\Phi$ is indeed bounded.

Comment: What is meant by $f|B$?

Comment: This is the restriction of $f$ to $B$.